# Unable to deploy from Jenkins to Jboss

Tags: maven, deployment, jboss, jenkins, jboss7.x

We are unable to deploy our application from  our BuildServer to our appliation server.

This is the maven command we use in Jenkins:

```
clean install  jboss-as:deploy -Pjboss7 -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

We have tried the following:

- Confirmed we can telnet from our BuildServer to our appliation server
- Upgrade Jboss maven plugin
- Started Jboss (on our application server) with

  $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0

Jenkins seems to hang at the following point:
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.12.GA
Authenticating against security realm: ManagementRealm

Answer (score 1):

Is the JBoss AS 7 working on the same machine as Jenkins?

Currently your binding your public interface to all network interfaces on the host machine (the -b command). You should also bind your management interface of the app server to a proper network interface (Jboss allows remote deployment only by the management interface). You can do it in the `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` (or `domain.xml` for domain mode) file. Find:

and set the `inet-address` to the ip of the machine which hosts the application server. You can also use the -bmanagement switch to bind the management interface, as such:

`$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -bmanagement=192.168.100.10`

You also stated, that you have a potential problem with authentication. Please post your maven plugin configuration. Note that the username and password you provide for the maven plugin should match the administrator user on JBoss (you can add him by choosing Management User in the `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/add-user.sh` promp). This is the most likely source of your problem - but it is hard to tell without any further information (for example something from the pom.xml file).

Also if the app server is working on the same machine as Jenkins, JBoss allows the "local user authentication" which basicaly checks if the call has originated from the same machine.

Additional source for network interface binding: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Command+line+parameters#Commandlineparameters-bindaddress